# Mysql select array

Tags: php, mysql, select

(edited)

Table "companies":
company -> "Example LTD"
categories (Varchar) -> "1,2,3,4"

When a visitor chooses to see companies in categori number "1", "Example LTD" should show (Also in 2,3 and 4)

I want to SELECT * FROM companies WHERE categories (contains the category number 1 for example)
Any idea?

Comment: What is the `categories` column? Does it contain one category per row? Or is it denormalized a bit, containing a comma-delim list or somthing? It's hard to tell from your question exactly what the data looks like.

Comment: The categories column contains more than one category per row. I want to select from ONE number and see if that number is in the colum (array)

Comment: @ Hundkartan: You've called the column an "array." MySQL has no "array" column type. Using correct, precise terminology and making an effort to be really clear about what you have will help enormously with people answering your question. What is the actual type of the column, and how is the data in it represented? Is it a `varchar` with commas? What?

Comment: Sorry! The column "categories" is set to "Varchar" with commas. For example: The Company "Test LTD" has the value "1,2,3" in the category field. And if a visitor chooses to see companies in categori number "1", "Test LTD" will show (And in 2 and 3)

Comment: @ Hundkartan: You can use the "edit" link to improve the question (for instance, adding that information). Konerak's answered it, though: 1) `FIND_IN_SET` will do that, and 2) That sort of denormalized structure is usually not a good idea. :-)

Comment: I've edited now, thanks. But how can I use FIND_IN_SET?
I've tried ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$currentcategory','category')" without any results

Comment: @ Hundkartan: The edited question is just as unclear as the unedited one. For your next question, think in terms of quoting code / table definitions, using complete sentences, and perferring clarity to brevity.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM companies WHERE categories IN (1,3,6,9)`

You can generate the IN-list dynamically in php:

```
$cats = join(',',$categories);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id IN ($cats)";
```

But do make sure that your $categories array is untainted (contains only safe data, to prevent MySQL injection)!

#### Update

You are storing categories in one CSV field? Ouch!

Well, if the user can only select one category, use FIND_IN_SET:

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE FIND_IN_SET(categories,1)
```

With multiple categories, no such thing. Use a loop to generate the different FIND_IN_SETs, separated by `AND`.

#### Please just normalize your data:

Make on table companies:

- CompanyID
- CompanyName

And a linktable for the categories:

- LinkID
- CompanyID
- Category

Comment: Isn't that when you want to select FROM an array?
I have a category (number 3 for example) and I want to select from companies where the commaseparated list contains number 3

Comment: Woah, are you storing the categories in one field, separated by comma's? That is bad database design :( MySQL has a [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) that can do what you want, but you really should consider making an extra table companycategories with one line per (company,category) pair!